# rsnapshot running for long time after deleting a large number of file

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot

We have been running a nightly backup on our Linux server for many years without issue. However, since deleting a large number of files (8gb worth) from one of the folders being backed up the backup process has still been running well into the next day and has had to be killed off.

I initially though it might be because it was trying to delete the 8gb off the rd1000 but, after wiping one of the rd1000 discs and having the same issue I'm not so sure now.

The backup process is 'rsnapshot -c $CONFIGFILE daily'.

$CONFIGFILE

```
#Rsnapshot backup parameters - Fri 29/11/19 02:00 am
#---------------------------------------------------

config_version          1.2
verbose                 5
loglevel                5
logfile                 /var/log/rsnapshot
lockfile                /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
cmd_cp                  /bin/cp
cmd_rm                  /bin/rm
cmd_rsync               /usr/bin/rsync
cmd_ssh         /usr/bin/ssh
cmd_logger              /usr/bin/logger
cmd_du                  /usr/bin/du
rsync_long_args         --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded --st
ats
link_dest               1
use_lazy_deletes        0
snapshot_root           /rd1000/backups/
interval                daily   1
backup                  /usr/sc4/pm/    localhost/
backup                  /usr/sc4/seachange/     localhost/
backup                  /usr/seawriter/ localhost/
backup                  /etc/   localhost/
backup                  /usr/bin/       localhost/
backup                  /usr/leanlifts/ localhost/
backup                  /usr/xml/       localhost/
backup                  /usr/tsh/       localhost/
backup                  /home/  localhost/
backup                  /usr/local/     localhost/
backup                  /var/spool/cron/        localhost/
backup                  /usr/spool/tsh/ localhost/
backup                  root@Brundleweb:/tmp/web/       Brundleweb/
backup                  root@Brundleweb:/tmp/mysql.bkup/                Brundlew
eb/dbase        rsync_long_args=--delete --numeric-ids --delete-excluded --stats
```

This is what is in /var/log/rsnapshot before I kill the process

```
[29/Nov/2019:03:00:59] require Lchown
[29/Nov/2019:03:00:59] Lchown module not found
[29/Nov/2019:03:00:59] /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /tmp/rsnapshot.conf.24861 daily: st
arted
[29/Nov/2019:03:00:59] Setting locale to POSIX "C"
[29/Nov/2019:03:00:59] echo 30828 > /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
[29/Nov/2019:03:00:59] /usr/bin/rsync -av --delete --numeric-ids --relative --de
lete-excluded --stats /usr/sc4/pm /rd1000/backups/daily.0/localhost/
```

Any help anybody could give me would be greatly appreciated.